# Probability help ball question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A bowl contains $5$ red balls, $3$ white, and $2$ blue balls. Two ball are selected without replacement.
**What is the probability that the two balls are a different colour?**

The answer that I got is $\frac{31}{45}$ but I'm not sure if it's correct...

Comment: Your answer is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to Foga's approach to is sum the probabilities in which the first ball chosen is red, white, or blue, respectively:

$${5\over10}\cdot{5\over9}+{3\over10}\cdot{7\over9}+{2\over10}\cdot{8\over9}={25+21+16\over90}={62\over90}={31\over45}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: The probability requested is $1-P_s$, where $P_s$ is the probability of choosing $2$ balls of the same colour...they can be either red, white or blue. So $$P_s=\frac{\binom{5}{2}+\binom{3}{2}+\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}}=\frac{10+3+1}{45}=\frac{14}{45}$$
Finally $$P=1-P_s\\=1-\frac{14}{45}\\=\frac{31}{45}$$

Comment: ok it's right thank you @foga

Comment: @user3335209 I got $\frac{26}{45}$ ...

Comment: ok...I see where I got it wrong...I'll edit! ;)

Comment: ok cool that what I got @foga

Comment: .... perfect! :)

Comment: I really appreciate it @Foga

Comment: you're welcome!